# Java: How to remove strings having the same prefix from a text file?

Tags: java, parsing

I need to replace some string from a text file such as "upcoming:event=123982".

The strings always start with "upcoming:event=". How can I remove them (including the digits) ? (I'm processing the text with Java).

Should I use wildcards ? something like "upcoming:event=*" ?

thanks

Comment: Is this values(123982) are always in fixed length(6 digits)?

Comment: may i know the size of the plain text file.

Comment: @Siva no.. sometimes 5 digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String str = "upcoming:event=123982";
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("upcoming:event=[0-9]*", "changed"));
```

Output: changed

Answer (score 1):

```
 String s="upcoming:event=123982;upcoming:event=100;upcoming:event=200;upcoming:event=900;upcoming:event=1987";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("upcoming:event=[0-9]*", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
123982;100;200;900;1987
```

Comment: replaceAll works, but not the wildcard in the end. I have several strings upcoming:event=123982, upcoming:event=232343, pcoming:event=888344. I need to replace all of them

Comment: @Patrict u dont need the wildcard *

Comment: My questions wasn't clear. I need to remove the numbers as well. (they can be 4, 5 or 6 digits long.

Comment: In your example, just ";;;;".

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.startsWith();`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks, but should I call this method for each single word of my text file !?

Comment: for each line, if I'm correctly understand your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is probably is not a good way you could

```
String text = "upcoming:event=*YOUR TEXT";      
System.out.println(text.replace("upcoming:event=*", ""));
```

Result will be YOUR TEXT in this case...